# Unable to find the path for uploading a file using streamlit Python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, streamlit

I'm writing a simple Python application where the user selects a file from their local file manager and tries to upload using streamlit.

I'm able to successfully take the file the user had given using `streamlit.uploader` and stored the file in a temp directory from the streamlit app folder but the issue is I can't give the path of the file of the file stored in the newly created directory in order to send the application into my gcp clouds bucket.

Adding my snippet below any help is appreciated :)

```
import streamlit as st
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage 
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
bucketName=('survey-appl-dev-public')
# Create API client.
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]
)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)

#create a bucket object to get bucket details 
bucket = client.get_bucket(bucketName)
file = st.file_uploader("Upload An file")
def main():
  if file is not None:
    file_details = {"FileName":file.name,"FileType":file.type}
    st.write(file_details)
    #img = load_image(image_file)
    #st.image(img, caption='Sunrise by the mountains')
    with open(os.path.join("tempDir",file.name),"wb") as f: 
      f.write(file.getbuffer())         
      st.success("Saved File")
      object_name_in_gcs_bucket = bucket.blob(".",file.name)
   object_name_in_gcs_bucket.upload_from_filename("tempDir",file.name)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've tried importing the path of the file using `cwd` command and also tried os library for file path but nothing worked.

Edited:
All I wanted to implement is make a file upload that is selected by customer using the dropbox of `file_uploader` option. I'm able to save the file into a temporary directory after the file is selected using the `file.getbuffer` as shown in the code but I couldn't make the code uploaded into the gcs bucket since its referring as str cannot be converted into int while I press the upload button.

Maybe its the path issue:

> "the code is unable to find the path of the file stored in the temp directory"

but I'm unable to figure out how to give the path to the upload function.

Error coding I'm facing:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'  
Traceback:
File "/home/raviteja/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/runtime/scriptrunner/script_runner.py", line 564, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "/home/raviteja/test/streamlit/test.py", line 43, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/raviteja/test/streamlit/test.py", line 29, in main
    object_name_in_gcs_bucket = bucket.blob(".",file.name)
File "/home/raviteja/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/bucket.py", line 795, in blob
    return Blob(
File "/home/raviteja/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 219, in __init__
    self.chunk_size = chunk_size  # Check that setter accepts value.
File "/home/raviteja/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 262, in chunk_size
    if value is not None and value > 0 and value % self._CHUNK_SIZE_MULTIPLE != 0:
```

Comment: Is your problem related to actually uploading the file to bucket or has to do with streamlit? Could you show us the error message when you run your code?

Comment: Are you running the app locally (from your pc) or from the cloud?

Comment: ive added the complete error log and full code please check and im running the app locally using streamlit run command

Comment: Added solution 2 in my answer. It does not save the file to disk but use the bytes data directly and send it to gcs bucket.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for response after days of struggle at last I've figured out the mistake im making.
I dont know if I'm right or wrong correct me if I'm wrong but this worked for me:

```
      object_name_in_gcs_bucket = bucket.blob("path-to-upload"+file.name)
```

Changing the , to + between the filepath and filename made my issue solve.

Sorry for the small issue.

Happy that I could solve it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import easygui
if st.button('Add file project.py'):
  file_absolut_path = easygui.fileopenbox(title='Add File', default="*.py")
  st.write(file_absolut_path)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a file using the Streamlit file uploader, the file is temporarily stored in the computer's memory. This means that the file is not saved permanently on the server or on the user's computer. Instead, the file is only available for the duration of the Streamlit app session. The default size is 200MB, but that can be modified. You can read it directly but you can get only the name of the file and not its path as the file is memory.

To upload the files you don't need to get its path, try this:

```
file_data = uploaded_file.getvalue()
    if file_data:
        container_name = 'zipfile'
        blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=container_name, blob=uploaded_file.name)
        blob_client.upload_blob(file_data, overwrite=True)
        st.write("File uploaded successfully!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some variables in your code and I guess you know what they represent. Try this out else make sure you add every relevant information to the question and the code snippet.

```py
def main():
    file = st.file_uploader("Upload file")
    if file is not None:
        file_details = {"FileName":file.name,"FileType":file.type}
        st.write(file_details)
        
        file_path = os.path.join("tempDir/", file.name)
        with open(file_path,"wb") as f: 
          f.write(file.getbuffer())         
        st.success("Saved File")

        print(file_path)


    def upload():
        file_name = file_path
        read_file(file_name)
        st.write(file_name)

        st.session_state["upload_state"] = "Saved successfully!"
        object_name_in_gcs_bucket = bucket.blob("gcp-bucket-destination-path"+ file.name)
        object_name_in_gcs_bucket.upload_from_filename(file_path)
        
    st.write("Youre uploading to bucket", bucketName)
    st.button("Upload file to GoogleCloud", on_click=upload)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

### Solution 1

```
import streamlit as st
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import storage
import os

STREAMLIT_SCRIPT_FILE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]
)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)

def main():
    bucketName = 'survey-appl-dev-public'
    file = st.file_uploader("Upload file")
    if file is not None:
        file_details = {"FileName":file.name,"FileType":file.type}
        st.write(file_details)

        with open(os.path.join("tempDir", file.name), "wb") as f:
            f.write(file.getbuffer())

        st.success("Saved File")

        bucket = client.bucket(bucketName)
        object_name_in_gcs_bucket = bucket.blob(file.name)

        # src_relative = f'./tempDir/{file.name}' # also works
        src_absolute = f'{STREAMLIT_SCRIPT_FILE_PATH}/tempDir/{file.name}'
        object_name_in_gcs_bucket.upload_from_filename(src_absolute)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

### Solution 2

Instead of saving the file to disk, use the file bytes directly using `upload_from_string()`.

###### References:

[Google Cloud upload_from_string](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/1.25.0/blobs#uploadfromstringdata-contenttypetextplain-clientnone-predefinedaclnone)
[Streamlit file uploader](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.file_uploader)

```
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(
    st.secrets["gcp_service_account"]
)
client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials)

def gcs_upload_data():
    bucket_name = 'your_gcs_bucket_name'

    file = st.file_uploader("Upload file")
    if file is not None:
        fname = file.name
        ftype = file.type

        file_details = {"FileName":fname,"FileType":ftype}
        st.write(file_details)

        # Define gcs bucket.
        bucket = client.bucket(bucket_name)
        bblob = bucket.blob(fname)

        # Upload the bytes directly instead of a disk file.
        bblob.upload_from_string(file.getvalue(), ftype)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gcs_upload_data()
```

Comment: will definetly try youre absolute path script :)